# Tar --acl option is missing from 1.25 version

Tags: linux, tar

I am trying to upgrade the `tar` version on my system.
Below is the current version.

```
# tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.17
```

If we execute `tar --help`

---

Handling of file attributes:

```
  --acls                 Save the ACLs to the archive
  --atime-preserve       don't change access times on dumped files
```

---

We can see `--acls` option available.

I downloaded 1.25 tar version, compiled and now I see `--acl` option is not available in the latest tar version.

Am I missing something ? or That option is replaced with some other option ?

Comment: I compiled 1.26 tar version and checked. Still same problem --acl option is not listed.

Comment: I use Redhat 5.6 (Tikanga) OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is that you are using `--` with your acl(option). Don't do that, you have to use a single dash(`-`).

So, the option would be `tar -acl archive.tar`!

This will help you for sure.

Comment: -acl option is not available.

 When i checked in latest 1.28 tar version. They have intorduced acl-option to be included. After that it is working.

Comment: @sandeepnagendra-Well, at least the above suggestion posted by me is working fine on `tar version 1.26` in CentOS 7! I hope you should upvote and accept my answer as I already gave the proper case. If it didn't, then leave the answer and post a better answer with full detail so that the future visitors should get a perfect suggestion!